# ADO.NET уникальные значения

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Всем привет. Почему возникает ошибка `Эти столбцы в данный момент не содержат уникальных значений.` Суть такова, что есть две таблицы `Users, Groups` в таблице `Users` есть столбик `Group` который берет значение из таблицы `Groups`. Вот их код:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Group]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [Message] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Groups] FOREIGN KEY ([Group]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([Id])
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups] (
    [Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([GroupName] ASC)
);
```

Дело в том что в таблице `Groups` `GroupName` должен быть уникальным - это понятно, ведь не может быть две одинаковых группы. Но вот в таблице `Users` номер группы может повторятся, ведь множество пользователей могут состоять в одной и той же группе. Однако когда я добавляю связи между таблицами и запускаю программу, то выдается вышеуказанная ошибка, которая исправляется только удалением не уникальных значений из столбца `Group` таблицы `Users`. Как сделать чтобы `Group` таблицы `Users` мог содержать не уникальные значение и при этом все работало ? Мой код:

```
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Users];select * from [Groups]", @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\sergey\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Users";
        ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Groups";
        ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("GropToGroupName", ds.Tables["Users"].Columns["Group"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["Id"]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор DataRelation:

```
public DataRelation(string relationName, DataColumn parentColumn, DataColumn childColumn);
```

Т.е. вам нужно поменять местами второй и третий параметры:

```
ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("GropToGroupName", ds.Tables[1].Columns["Id"], ds.Tables["Users"].Columns["Group"]));
```